# How to find out some specific meaning of something in ZF1 api doc

Tags: php, zend-framework, api-doc

A Zend_Form like this:

```
class Application_Form_Registration extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Form Elements & Other Definitions Here ... */
        $$this->setMethod('post');

        //first name
        $this->addElement('text', 'email', array(
            'label'         => 'First name',
            'required'      => true,
            'filters'       => array('StringTrim'),
        ));

        //last name
        $this->addElement('text', 'lastname', array(
            'label'         => 'Last name', 
            'required'      => true,
            'filters'       => array('StringTrim')
        ));

        $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
            'ignore'        => true,
            'label'         => 'Submit'
        ));

        $this->addElement('hash', 'csrf', array(
            'ignore'    => true,
        ));
    }


}
```

I read through the ZF1 1.12 API and reference document, but I can't find the meaning of the flag "ignore" in the Zend_Form::addElement() configure options.

The api doc is just this:
[image]

Surely I googled it and find it but this is not the way to work. How to I find the meaning of certain specific stuff. I don't suppose that I need to read the source code?

Just take this `addElement()` as an example, am I missing somewhere to look further? Nothing in [Zend_Config](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.12/classes/Zend_Config.html) class that I can find about `ignore` flag either.

Answer (score 0):

As I know `ignore` flag defines if form values (`$form->getValues()`) will contain element value. If ignore is set to true for some element than form values (`$form->getValues()`) will not contain this element value.

Comment: Thanks, but actually i was curious to know how you learn about this. Like I explained in the question, I don't know where to look to find such information.

Comment: > I don't know where to look to find such information. - on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

ZF Documentation can be...lacking sometimes.  The API docs for the ignore flag state:

```
getIgnore( ) : bool Get ignore flag (used when retrieving values at form level)
```

Which hints that the `ignore` flag has something to do with the behavior of `Zend_Form` `GetValues()` but it's not really spelled out.

In these cases I like to go straight to the source code so I can see for myself:

```
public function getValues($supressArrayNotation = false)
{
    ...
    foreach ($this->getElements() as $key => $element) {
        if (!$element->getIgnore()) {
    ...
}
```

You can see that the getValues() function in Zend_Form will check the `ignore` flag on each element before adding the value to the return array.  If the flag is true, the value won't be included.